# IBM Data Science Experience (DSX): dashdb - How to push a new data set

Tags: rstudio, data-science-experience

I'm trying to push a new data set (say in a csv format) into DB2 warehouse on cloud. How to do that?

Any idea please.

Comment: This blog post might help: https://medium.com/ibm-data-science-experience/how-to-use-db2-warehouse-on-cloud-in-data-science-experience-notebooks-c42730b86392 It's about putting data into DB2 from a Notebook. Here's another blog article about working with DB2 in an R environment https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/connecting/connect_connecting_rstudio.html

Answer (score 0):

Your DB2 warehouse has a web console available in IBM Cloud. Go to https://www.ibm.com/cloud/, from the pull-down menu 'My cloud console', select 'Dashboard'. Log in, and you should find your DB2 instance. From there, you'll find a link to 'Open' the instance dialog. From there, you should find a big red button that says "Load Data". :)